# Stripe different currency for different plan?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to develop 2 subscription plans for a client. Plan A they will pay CAD $5/month. Plan B they will pay USD $10 / month. Because this is a special client so we have to design a new plan they will pay in CAD. How do I design in Stripe? since when I use API `stripe.subscriptions.create`, it shows this issue when they want to switch between plans

`` Error: The specified price uses `usd` which doesn't match the expected currency of `cad`. Use `cad` instead. ``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Customers are [single currency](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer#currency), meaning that you can only have subscriptions (and invoices, balances etc) in one currency. Once the default currency for the customer is set, it [cannot be changed](https://support.stripe.com/questions/setting-a-customers-default-currency). If you need Subscriptions in two currencies, you will need to manage two Stripe Customers for your real-world customer.

This does not restrict your ability to create one-time payments for that Customer (such as with the Payment Intents API) in any supported currency.